# They went on a road trip last week - is the road trip finished or not?

Tags: meaning

Example 1,

> They went on a road trip last week.

Example 2,

> They embarked on a road trip last week.

When words like "go on" and "embark on" are used in the past tense, do they mean that the whole trip has finished, or do they mean the trip was started but we do not know whether it is finished or not?

Comment: It is ambiguous in both examples.

Comment: With no other context I would understand Example 1 to mean the trip is now finished, but I would not assume that for example 2.

Answer (score 1):

Without other context, I'd assume that the trip was finished.  The reason is that, if they were still on a road trip, that is more important.  If they are still on the trip you'd say "They are on a road trip".  Of course, context would change that.  If you said, "They went on a road trip last week, and will come home tomorrow." for example

On the other hand, in the second example, the speaker has made an effort to use a rare word that explicitly means "began a journey". And I'd assume that t the reason for this was that the speaker only means "the journey began" (and probably doesn't even know if where they are).